# I need to generate a GUID,help

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, uuid

I need help with an SSIS package, I need to generate a GUID code every time I register a row of data, can someone explain how it is done?

In the SISS package, the data is extracted from an excel file, this does not have the GUID id that are necessary to insert the information in the database, therefore, I am looking for the message that the ethl generates when I insert the data.

SQL Server Data Tools

Comment: When you say "Register a row of data" - do you mean `INSERT` a row of data?

Comment: I mean insert data, I explain more carefully in the question.

Comment: [This](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/02/create-guid-column-in-ssis.html) post shows you how to add a guid column via a script component

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a NEWID?  I usually use NEWID when I want to make GUIDs.

```
SELECT NEWID() AS GUID;
```

You can also go about it via the SSIS package itself:

1. Script task or Execute SQL Task which generates a list of GUIDs into a table or C# List. (Table columns: ID, GUID)
2. Import the data into a Staging table with an IDENTITY column.
3. Join to the GUID table (On ID=ID) and use the GUID column to import into the final table

OR

1. Generate the GUIDs and store them as a list (or table)
2. Use a "FOR EACH" loop task to populate the GUIDs one by one as you import the data (using either a C#/VB Script task or a Execute SQL Script task).

Here is some quick SQL to get your Temporary GUID table up and running.
You can run this early on in the package as an Execute SQL task.
Just import your own data into a table with an ID identifier, then join to this table on ID = ID.

```
--Create temp table to house GUIDs
CREATE TABLE #TempGUIDTable
(ID  INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,GUID NVARCHAR(100));

--Loop Counter variable
DECLARE @LoopCounter   INT = 0
       ,@NumberOfGUIDS INT = 100; --This can be dynamic as an inbound variable

--Loop through and create number of desired Guids
WHILE (@LoopCounter <@NumberOfGUIDS)
BEGIN
    --Insert X GUIDs into Table
    INSERT INTO #TempGUIDTable 
    (GUID)
    SELECT NEWID();

    --Increase counter
    SET @LoopCounter += 1;
END;

--Validate/Join here
SELECT * FROM #TempGUIDTable;

--Drop Temp Table
DROP TABLE #TempGUIDTable;
```

Comment: Since the user is pulling data from an Excel spreadsheet inside SSIS, it won't be quite as simple as running a query.

Comment: @RDFozz I see your point but I believe it would be pretty simple.  Just have a variable within the SSIS package called GUID and generate/write.  I assume they could also generate a list of GUIDs as a table and just pick from them using "Execute SQL Script" or a C#/VB Script task and a ForEach Loop task.  I did something similar with generating users' ages dynamically for a Payroll SSIS package.

Comment: Selecting a single GUID into a variable and using that in their insert is only valid if inserting a single row (It's possible their spreadsheet just has one data row, but it seems unlikely). The other suggestions are excellent, and I recommended editing them into the answer.

Comment: Great point.  It would be tedious selecting a single GUID into a variable one at a time.  Suggestion taken.  Editing :)